# Geocode addresses using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-online

I have an ArcGIS Online subscription, however I continue to get an error similar to the one below when attempting to geocode a dbf of street addresses in ArcGIS for Desktop. I tried both 10.3 & 10.2.2.

> ArcGIS Online subscription is required for geocoding the table of
>   addresses

I was able to geocode 11k addresses at one point yesterday, however I have only gotten this error in subsequent attempts - any ideas?

Comment: Are you storing the geocoding results or not? AGOL Geocoding is a paid service, [requiring credits](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/credits/). If you've already done 11k addresses, perhaps you have exhausted your credits? If credits are not the issue, then more information is needed about how you're trying to do the geocoding, and whether you've [properly authenticated](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/using_ArcGIS_Online_geocode_service/00250000004v000000/) before trying to do so.

Comment: Geocoding addresses is a costly operation, check your [arcgis.com subscription status](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/view-status.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1D001100A7A24CDF85A09169E0A424ED) to see how you've spent your credits and how many credit are still available.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I think you are correct since I received an email to the effect.  Are there subscriptions that allow for unlimited geocoding - or another service that will allow large batch geocoding?  This must have been a change in the last couple of years, because I remember previously being able to geocode several hundred thousand addresses directly from ArcGIS desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Online (AGOL) Geocoding is a paid service, [requiring credits](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/credits/) to use - 1,000 addresses for 40 credits. As GISGe points out, you can [check the status of your subscription](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/view-status.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1D001100A7A24CDF85A09169E0A424ED) to see your balances. Assuming you have [properly authenticated](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/using_ArcGIS_Online_geocode_service/00250000004v000000/), and based on your comment of receiving an email, it appears the problem is you have exhausted your credits. Per the first link above, the cost for unlimited geocodes is 'Contact Us'. :)

As far as I know, AGOL geocoding has always been a paid service. It was and still is possible to geocode from within ArcGIS Desktop for free, no limit - but you have to use the right geocoder/locator/your own data. Note that some geocoding services were [discontinued at the end of 2013](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/28/2nd-reminder-legacy-geocoding-and-routing-services-will-be-retired-on-december-31-2013/) and replaced by AGOL services.

We have two very popular questions regarding geocoding services with a number of alternatives, both free and paid:

- [Geocoding USA addresses that cannot be sent over internet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6/)
- [Bulk Geocode 20 million records](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21382/)